# Typing antd form.create when component uses a generic type

Tags: reactjs, typescript, antd

I am having trouble properly typing a functional component that is wrapped in Form.create() that contains a generic.

Here is a sample of the functional component

```
interface IProps<T> extends FormComponentProps {
    left: T;
    right: T;
}

const SampleComponent = <T extends object>(props: IProps<T>): JSX.Element => 
{ leaving this out for simplicity };

export default Form.create()(SampleComponent);
```

When I try and use this component it complains that the props left and right do not exist, which makes sense since I can't figure out how to pass the generic type through.

For components that do not have a generic type I know to do `Form.create<Props>(Component)` but I am not sure how to properly pass along that generic type. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FunctionComponent` which accepts a type argument, then declare the generic type (with whatever constraints, such as `extends object`) you want for your props in the prop interface like you're currently doing.  Then you can pass whatever generic you're using as a parameter into the generic OF the generic for your component type. This will type your props automatically, so there's no need to declare them explicitly as your prop type.  For example:

```
interface IProps<T extends object> extends FormComponentProps {
  left: T;
  right: T;
}

const SampleComponent: FunctionComponent<IProps<MyGenericType>> = ({ left, right }) => {
  return <div/>
}
```

Where MyGenericType is the type of left and right which also extends the object type.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the last line as a reference from https://ant.design/components/form/#Using-in-TypeScript

```
Form.create<IProps>()(SampleForm);
```

Comment: This is not correct. I stated in the question that this does not work for generics.